# Update user with DirectoryService

Tags: active-directory, directoryservices

I'm writing a small application which updates my AD with info from a DB table, but are having trouble finding examples of best practices.

As far as I understand, I'll need to:

- create a `DirectorySearcher` with a filter `objectClass=user` and search for the given cn
- if found, I need to use `result.getDirectoryEntry` to get a handle to the actual object,
- Update all the values to my `entryobject` with the one's from the db and then commit changes

Is that it or am I totally lost, any hints or examples are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // update the properties you need to 
   user.DisplayName = "Joe Blow";
   user.Description = "Some description";

   // save back your changes
   user.Save();
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

If you need to search a whole bunch of users, you can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
// and with the first name (GivenName) of "Bruce"
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
qbeUser.GivenName = "Bruce";

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
    UserPrincipal user = found as UserPrincipal;

    if(user != null)
    {
       // update the properties you need to 
       user.DisplayName = "Joe Blow";
       user.Description = "Some description";

       // save back your changes
       user.Save();
    }
}
```

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've heard about the AccountManagement, someone told me it was very limited to which attributes you could access? I'm storing a lot of data in extensionattributes, can I still use the S.DS.AM?

Comment: @elwis: read the article I've linked to! You can extend the `UserPrincipal` class to suit your needs and yes, you can definitely still use S.DS.AM for your task! If all else fails, you can always call `.GetUnderlyingObject()` and get your hands on the `DirectoryEntry` that belongs to that `UserPrincipal` and handle updates of extended attributes there.

Comment: Hav to comment. I wasn't able to go with that solution but I still read your article and it really seem to be a great solution. Hopefully next time, thanks for the link